# Error saving compilation unit to cache file: ins-360-frontend\target\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache-00000189CF16F886

Tags: java, gwt

When I clean install my frontend project, I get the following errormsg and can not finish the build successfully. I tried to delete everything under target, cleaned project but did not help. I am using eclipse, maven 3 and jdk 11

```
[INFO] [ERROR] Error saving compilation unit to cache file: C:\work\workspace\ins-360-parent\ins-360-frontend\target\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache-7b9fbb59f8661539c34f46974ce5fb573aac79fc-43B58CEE191BCD9CEF476AFB1F05E1EC-00000189CF16F886
[INFO] java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
[INFO]  at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.readBytes(Native Method)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.read(RandomAccessFile.java:406)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCache.transferToStream(DiskCache.java:165)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCacheToken.writeObject(DiskCacheToken.java:73)
[INFO]  at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor37.invoke(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1130)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:442)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CachedCompilationUnit.writeObject(CachedCompilationUnit.java:230)
[INFO]  at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1130)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCacheDir$OpenFile.writeUnit(PersistentUnitCacheDir.java:373)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCacheDir.writeUnit(PersistentUnitCacheDir.java:194)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache$BackgroundService$4.run(PersistentUnitCache.java:413)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[INFO] [1;31mBUILD FAILURE[m
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[INFO] Total time:  06:15 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-07T10:22:27+02:00
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal [32morg.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.10.0:compile[m [1m(default)[m on project [36mins-360-frontend[m: [1;31mCommand failed with status 1:[m
[ERROR] [1;31mcmd.exe /X /C "C:\work\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\work\workspace\ins-360-parent\ins-360-frontend\target/tmp -Dgwt.jjs.permutationWorkerFactory=com.google.gwt.dev.ThreadedPermutationWorkerFactory -Dgwt.jjs.maxThreads=4 -Xmx8G com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -logLevel INFO -war C:\work\workspace\ins-360-parent\ins-360-frontend\target\war -localWorkers 12 -XnoclassMetadata -XnocheckCasts -failOnError -XfragmentCount -1 -sourceLevel 1.8 -generateJsInteropExports -style OBFUSCATED -XmethodNameDisplayMode ONLY_METHOD_NAME -deploy C:\work\workspace\ins-360-parent\ins-360-frontend\target\gwt-deploy -gen C:\work\workspace\ins-360-parent\ins-360-frontend\target\generated-sources\gwt com.bearingpoint.davinci.gui.AbacusIns"[m
[ERROR] -> [1m[Help 1][m
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the [1m-e[m switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the [1m-X[m switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [1m[Help 1][m http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```